# How to fix java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url using OKHTTP3

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

When I try to execute the following code for Websocket in Okhttp, I get an error message:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url:wws://www.mydomain.com/websocket

```
String WEBSOCKET_URL = "wws://www.mydomain.com/websocket";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(0,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(WEBSOCKET_URL).build();
        WebSocket webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeCoach.this, "Connected to the Websocket server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, @Nullable okhttp3.Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeCoach.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not WWS, but WSS. Change your url to `String WEBSOCKET_URL = "wss://www.mydomain.com/websocket";`